# 1 string needing to provide 2 outputs

Tags: java, string

It wants me to return the "message" String which is to display the following output. If the order is valid but it isn't discounted then there is no need to have Discount in the output, but if the order is valid and there is a discount than it needs a Discount in the output. Now, I've tried a few things and I just can't figure it out =/

The getOrderDetails methods main job is to return the message instance 
variable. If the order is valid and it is not discounted then it is to set the 
message so that it is displayed as follows (without the discount instance 
variable) when it is returned using the appropriate instance variables  as 
follows:

```
- Order number: 1
- Product name: Pencil
- Product Price: $0.6
- Order Quantity: 6
- Total Price: $3.6
```

If the order is valid and discounted it is to change message so that it includes 
the discount instance variable as follows:

```
- Order number: 1
- Product name: Pencil
- Product Price: $0.6
- Order Quantity: 6
- Discount: 10%
- Total Price: $3.24
```

If the order is not valid it is just to return the message instance variable.

```
public class Order {

    public String productName; //Name
    public double price;  //Price
    public double discount;  //Discount
    public int quantity;  //Quantity
    public double total; //Total for the price multiplied with quantity (with or without discount)
    public String message; //Message
    public boolean isDiscounted = false; //Set to false, but if it's true, the discount comes in
    public boolean isValidOrder = true; //Set to true, but if it's false, the Order becomes invalid and Message comes in
    public static int orderNum = 0; //Order number set to 0 as default


        public void setProductName(String productName) {
            this.productName = productName;
        }//Set the name
        public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }//Set the price
        public void setDiscount(double discount) {
            this.discount = discount;
        }//Set the discount
        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }//Set the price
        public void setOrderDetails(boolean isValidOrder, boolean isDiscounted) {
            this.isValidOrder = isValidOrder;
        }//Set the Order Details
        public String getProductName() {
            return productName;
        }//Get the name
        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }//Get the price
        public double getDiscount() {
            return discount;
        }//Get the discount
        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }//Get the price

        public Order() { //Constructor 1
            isValidOrder = false;
            message =  "**ERROR** : Order number cannot be totalled as no details have been supplied.";
            orderNum++;
        }

      public Order(String productName, int quantity){  //Constructor 2
          this.productName = productName;
          this.quantity = quantity;
          getPrice(this.productName);


          if(isValidOrder != false){
              calculate();
          }
          orderNum++;

      }

    public Order(String productName, int quantity, double discount){ //Constructor 3
        this.productName = productName;
        testQuantity(quantity);
        getPrice(productName);
                this.discount = discount;

          if(isValidOrder != false){
              calculate();
          }
                  orderNum++;
    }

    public String getOrderDetails(){ //Order Details

        if(isValidOrder == true && isDiscounted == true){

            message = "Order Number: " + orderNum + "\n" + "Product Name: " + productName + "\n" + "Product Price: $" + price + "\n" + "Order Quantity: " + this.quantity + "\n" + "Discount: " + this.discount + "%" + "\n" + "Total Price: $" + total;  

        } 
                else if(isValidOrder == true && isDiscounted == false){

            message = "Order Number: " + orderNum + "\n" + "Product Name: " + productName + "\n" + "Product Price: $" + price + "\n" + "Order Quantity: " + this.quantity + "\n" + "Total Price: $" + total;  
        }  
                return message; 
    }


    public void calculate(){ //Calculate for total
        if(this.isDiscounted == false){
            total = quantity * price;
        } 
                else {
            total = quantity * price - quantity * price * (discount / 100 );  
        }
    }

    public void getPrice(String productName){ //Switch so you can find what item ordered and allocate the correct price
        switch(productName){
        case "Pencil":
            this.price = 0.6;
            break;
        case "Pen":
            this.price = 0.3;
            break;
        case "Ruler":
            this.price = 1.2;
                        break;
        case "Pencil Sharpener":
            this.price = 0.3;
            break;
        case "Compass":
            this.price = 4.5;
            break;
        case "Eraser":
            this.price = 4.5;
            break;
        case "Scissors":
            this.price = 2.5;
                        break;
        case "Pencil Case":
            this.price = 10.0;
            break;
        default:
            this.price = 0.0;
            this.isValidOrder = false;
            this.message = "**ERROR** : Invalid product name";
                        break;
                }
    }

    public void testDiscount(double discount) { //Testing for a Discount
        if (discount <=0) {
            isDiscounted = false;
            message = "**ERROR** : The discount rate cannot be lower than or equal to 0.";
        }
        else if (discount >50) {
            isDiscounted = false;
            message = "**ERROR** : The discount rate cannot be higher than 50.";
        } 
       else {
       this.discount = discount;        
       this.isDiscounted = true;     
        }  
    }


    public void testQuantity(int quantity){  //Testing for Quantity
           if(quantity <=0) {
                isValidOrder = false;
                message = "**ERROR** : Invalid quantity. Quantity cannot be 0 or less.";
                }
            else if (quantity >1000) {
                isValidOrder = false;
                message = "**ERROR** : Invalid quantity. Quantity cannot be greater than 1000.";
            }  
                else {
                isValidOrder = true;
                this.quantity = quantity;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Create your own class and make it have several properties, a `String message` and a `boolean discount` for example. I have a little bad feeling about your code design though.

Comment: can you share the full code

Comment: what are you supposed to return when the order is invalid?

Comment: If the order is invalid it is just to return the message instance

Comment: And the full code has been edited in

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't allow an instance of `Order` to be invalid in the first place. To do this, create mutator methods (aka setters) to set the values such as discount. `public boolean setDiscount(float discountPercentage);` would return true if the value is valid (`0 <= value <= 100`), and set the value only if the value is valid. Your design in general could do with some improvements. Usually `Order` contains `LineItems`, which in turn contain `Item` and quantity.

Comment: As an asside, don't use double to represent the cost. Use [BigDecimal](http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial)